# How to get the small arrow next to a tab

Tags: android

It might be a silly question 
 but i want to know how to get back the small arrow next to the app tab that enables me to explore what`s inside

[image]

[image]

Comment: put something in it then it will appear. simply it means there is nothing to show in app folder

Comment: this is a small project i am training on . and i can get the arrow when i am in the ( project tab ) not the ( android tab )

Comment: I guess there is nothing inside

Comment: I edited the post and added a new image

Comment: I suspect your project is not configured properly. create new project and copy files there. hope it helps.